# How to parse all the coefficients of a polynomial string in python

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing

I have a .txt file which contains huge polynomials stored as strings. A representative example would be as follows.
`6*n101110111*n111111111 + 3*n101111101 + 6*n101111111 + n111111111`
But in general the polynomials consist of 'n + str(all possible binary digits of length 9)' multiplied in different orders with coefficients. The number of terms and '+' is not known beforehand. 
The result should be,

```
[6,3,6,1]
```

Even better would be getting it as a dictionary

```
{ n101110111*n111111111: 6, n101111101: 3, n101111111: 6, n111111111 :1}
```

Comment: Does the string you show constitute a typical line in the file? If so, is every line of the file of interest and is the `6*n101110111*n111111111` part always at the beginning of a line? This example has four terms separated by plus signs. Do all strings of interest have exactly four terms? If not, what is the maximum number of terms? Can some of the plus signs be minus signs? Please provide this information by editing your question rather than doing so in a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have a solution for you:

```py
stringList = yourStringHere.split("+")
outputDict = {}

for sub in stringList:
    values = sub.split("*")
    try:
        baseNum = int(values[0])
        poly = "*".join(values[1:]).strip()
    except:
        baseNum = 1
        poly = "*".join(values).strip()
    outputDict[poly] = baseNum
```

The only downside of this approach will be that the dictionary contains unique keys and therefore if you have other similar powers in your dictionary they will be overwritten.

Comment: I like how neat the solution is but  'n111111111 :1' will not be parsed by your solution

Answer (score 3):

A regex like this `((\d)?\*?((?:n\d+)(?:\*n\d+)*))`( [`Regex demo`](https://regex101.com/r/8EW3yb/1)) will do the job

```
line = "6*n101110111*n111111111 + 3*n101111101 + 6*n101111111 + n111111111"
res = {}

matches = re.findall(r"(?:(\d)?\*?((?:n\d+)(?:\*n\d+)*))", line)
print(matches)  # [('6', 'n101110111*n111111111'), ('3', 'n101111101'), ('6', 'n101111111'), ('', 'n111111111')]

for match in matches:
    res[match[1]] = match[0] or 1
print(res)  # {'n101110111*n111111111': '6', 'n101111101': '3', 
               'n101111111': '6', 'n111111111': 1}
```

Answer (score 3):

you could use:

```
import re

s = '6*n101110111*n111111111 + 3*n101111101 + 6*n101111111 + n111111111'

l = [g.group().split('*', 1)  for g in re.finditer(r'\b([\dn*]+)\b', s)]
{e[-1]: 1 if len(e) == 1 else int(e[0]) for e in l}
```

output:

```
{'n101110111*n111111111': 6,
 'n101111101': 3,
 'n101111111': 6,
 'n111111111': 1}
```

Comment: You can shorten your character class to `[*n\d]`. Nice pythoning, though. ^^

Answer (score 1):

You could use the regular expression

```
r" (?:(\d+)\*)?([^ +-]+)
```

[Python demo](https://regex101.com/r/zEsP9H/4/)

The regex engine performs the following operations for each match:

```
(?:        # begin a non-capture group
  (\d+)    # match 1+ digits in capture group 1
  \*       # match '*'
)          # end non-capture group
?          # optionally match non-capture group
([^ +-]+)  # match 1+ chars other than spaces, '+', and '-' in
           # capture group 2
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Python, but creating a hash from the contents of the capture groups should be straightforward, comparable to the Ruby code `str.gsub(r).with_object({}) {|_,h| h[$2] = ($1 || 1).to_i}
  #=> {"n101110111*n111111111"=>6, "n101111101"=>3, "n101111111"=>6, "n111111111"=>1}`, where `r` is the regular expression.